# Evaluate the integral $ \ \int_{\gamma} z^{\large \frac{1}{2}} dz \ $

Tags: complex-analysis

**Evaluate the integral** $$ \int_{\gamma} z^{\large \frac{1}{2}} dz \ $$

**for the principal branch of** $ \ \large z^{\frac{1}{2}} \ $ **along the the contour indicated below**:

[image]

**Answer:**

Take the principal branch:

$f(z)=\sqrt z=\sqrt e^{\frac{i \theta}{2}} , \ 0 \leq \theta \leq  2 \pi \ $

But how to evaluate the integral?

Comment: You could use path independence https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Path_independence

Comment: $ \int_{\gamma} \sqrt zdz=\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{i}{2} e^{i \theta} d \theta \ $ . Is it correct?

Comment: *Hint.* You know the antiderivative of $z^{1/2}$, which is $\frac{2}{3}z^{3/2}$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$. So the answer is $$\int_{\gamma} z^{1/2} \, dz = \left[ \frac{2}{3}z^{3/2} \right]_{\pi}^{i}=\frac{2}{3}\left( \frac{-1+i}{\sqrt{2}} - \pi^{3/2} \right).$$

Comment: @SangchulLee is correct.  If there is an anti-derivative of your integrand defined on your curve, then you get the answer by subtracting the values of that anti-derivative at the endpoints of the contour.